# Android customize action bar with api<11

Tags: android, android-actionbar

how can I customize my action bar with api<11? I can't use actionBarSherlock because I got an issue related to my custom rom...is there a way to do that?

Comment: what you want to customize in actionbar??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go For sherlock Action bar. h[ere is link for the same](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Here is detailed info on [how to implement it](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html)

- Make sure your project uses Android 4.0+ as the build target and that
  you have the compatibility/support library added. (You can
  right-click the project, select Android Toots > Add Support Library)
- Download the ActionBarSherlock library project and import it into
  Eclipse.
- Right-click your main project, select Properties, and select Android
  in the left pane. In the bottom half of the window, click the Add
  button and select the ActionBarSherlock project. Click OK.
- Instead of using regular Activities and Fragments, you use ones from
  the Sherlock Library. They have the same names, but prefixed with
  "Sherlock" (SherlockActivity, SherlockFragment, etc.)
- To access the actionbar in code, you call getSupportActionBar(). This
  returns either the regular actionbar (for Honeycomb and later) or the
  Sherlock actionbar (for pre-Honeycomb).
- Theming instructions are on the ActionBarSherlock website.

You can set android:minSdk in android manifest to lower sdk say 2.2 but built have to build in target 4.

So, **it will work on handsets** with api level < 11.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own `ActionBar`