# Android action bar menu in tablet

Tags: android

At my new application that I created, I got auto generated code for creating menu:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And I added item at menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"></item>

</menu>
```

But there is no menu button, am I missing something?

Comment: Try `android:showAsAction="always"` instead of `android:showAsAction="never"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

In your menu definition you put:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Change it to:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Check this example, including an icon for the menu:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_calendar"
    android:title="@string/calendar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_calendar_holo_light"        
    android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

`always` means the button will always be displayed. You can replace it by `ifRoom` if it is a menu such as Settings that should appear in the menu as an option but not displayed all the time.

`withtext` means that the title of the menu will be displayed beside the icon if there is enough place for it.

Details about all these options are available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

For the rest, you need to create and show the `ActionBar` in your `onCreate()` function:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    //you might need this line if you are not using the Holo theme
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();

(...)
```

Comment: Have you sorted out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the **import** you are using. Check example below

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

You should use `Menu` and `MenuInflater` of actionbarsherlock..

Check out this link on [implemention of ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16398402/2345913)

Comment: It is not necessary to install Sherlock, only if he is targeting previous Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/item1"></item>
```