# How to add logo on top-left corner of each screen in android application?

Tags: android

I want to add an application logo on each screen of an application. 
Is there any way to make such centralized change from a single place instead of adding logo in layout file for each screen?

Comment: Yes, use SherlockActionBar Here is coplete details to implement [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398402/2345913)

Comment: Action Bar as suggested by @RaghavSood http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to make such centralized change from a single place instead of adding logo in layout file for each screen.

[image]

**'1'** is the palce for the ***app icon***, which establishes your app's identity. It can be replaced with a different logo or branding if you wish. Important: If the app is currently not displaying the top-level screen, be sure to display the Up caret to the left of the app icon, so the user can navigate up the hierarchy.

You can also add additional [Navigation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) here.

Comment: needs to be updated for Toolbar use. http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting an API over **14** (Ice Cream Sandwich),

```
getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.your_logo_name);
```

You'll have to do this for every Activity. What I usually do is to set one "BaseActivity" which I extend other activities from. This becomes helpful especially later on when standardizing other things like common functions and settings.

Answer (score 0):

as Raghav said you can use ActionBar. [See this example for Actionbar](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

If you don't want to use action bar then you can create a single layout like with name "logo.xml"

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/icon_image"/>
```

then use this layout file in any of your layout by including this layout file like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/logo"/>
    <!--your other code-->
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specifies your application icon in manifest.
[in activity tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

in that 
android:icon="@drawable/your_logeHere"
that will show in title bar.

Comment: I already have it in application tag. `<application android:name=".hmi.SentryApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">`.But the problem is that out of 8 screens this logo is only visible on 2 screens.

Comment: @AkashPatel you can define in activity tag also.

Comment: ok. but why it is showing in 2 screens only? Is there any possibility to stop showing an icon on a particular screen? If yes then I'll check in files for the screens where logo is not appearing.

Comment: @AkashPatel you have to specifies app icon in activity tag. in that in which activity you want to show icon specified in manifest file.

Comment: I understood how to add icon using <activity> tag. But my doubt is that if I add icon to <application> tag and don't want to show icon in just one screen then can I disable it for that particular screen?

Comment: @AkashPatel in application tag when you specifies icon in application tag. that will appear in menu list. and main activity only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30462/discussion-between-akash-patel-and-bhavesh-jethani)