# Action bar appears on some devices and not others

Tags: android

I have written an app which has an action bar at the top.

The app works fine on my Galaxy SII (Android 4.0.4) and I see the action bar, but on my Galaxy tab (Android 3.1), the action bar does not appear - though everything else works fine.

I don't know whether its just the case that 3.1 does not support it or I have a bug in my code. And if its just that 3.1 doesn't support it, how come it didn't crash?

Comment: I would suggest to use ActionBarSherlock for your action bar. [here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398402/2345913) for complete implementation

Comment: If you want to use ActionBar APIs, such as to add navigation modes and modify action bar styles, you should set the minSdkVersion to "11" or greater. If you want your app to support older versions of Android, there are ways to use a limited set of ActionBar APIs on devices that support API level 11 or higher, while still running on older versions.  this what the doc says http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: if your min sdk is 11 or higher it should work. api 11 is 3.0 so i guess it should work

Comment: if your min sdk is 11 or above you can set the project theme as theme.holo which is the default theme for action bar

Comment: @Mick you found your error? if you found please post answer to your questions and accept it. I have same error

Comment: I ended up using action bar sherlock, and then it worked.