# Actionbar that can work in android gingerbread and higher version

Tags: android

I am new to android, need help for the Actionbar that can be work in android gingerbread and higher version. done some google search. need example code like top left option (settings,sin out) options with logo.

Comment: Use this library http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Use SherlockActionBar

Comment: [refer here for detailed implementation of Sherlock actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398402/2345913)

Comment: Use this link as it is working code http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-menus-to-action-bar-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/

Answer (score 2):

Want to try something new from android?
Then visit this link you will get your way.
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for replay need an example working code will be grate help for me

Answer (score 1):

Use the [actionbarsherlock's library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Here a tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY

Edit:

And instead of using ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); in your activity.

use ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); and replace activity by SherlockActivity.

And don't forget to import sherlock: http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

Comment: Hi thanks for replay need an example working code will be grate help for me

Comment: ActionBarSherlock contains a heap of example projects.

Comment: Thanks I got where i am missing and its working....